# How to apply group by on xslt

Tags: xslt, grouping

I am trying group some xml by the project id

I can used xslt v 2.0

I think I need to use **for-each-group** but I couldn't find a example that was similar 
(because of the parent element)

Here is the example data

```
<projects>
    <project>
        <id>141</id>
        <name>Project 141</name>
        <identifier>am-1000171</identifier>
        <description>Project 141</description>
    </project>
    <project>
        <id>120</id>
        <name>Project 120</name>
        <identifier>am-1000199</identifier>
        <description>Project 120</description>
    </project>
    <project>
        <id>109</id>
        <name>Project 109</name>
        <identifier>am-1000143</identifier>
        <description>Project 108</description>
        <parent id="141" name="Project 141" />
    </project>
    <project>
        <id>53</id>
        <name>Project 53</name>
        <identifier>am-1000101</identifier>
        <description>Project 53</description>
        <parent id="141" name="Project 141" />
    </project>
    <project>
        <id>24</id>
        <name>Project 25</name>
        <identifier>am-1000019</identifier>
        <description>Project 24</description>
        <parent id="53" name="Project 53" />
    </project>
</projects>
```

The output would need to look like the following

```
120 
141
> 53
>> 24
> 109
```

Is there an example that anybody could please point me towards to get an idea of how to resolve?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think grouping helps, the key here is a "key" for cross-referencing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="indent" select="'>'"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="project[parent]" use="parent/@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/projects/project[not(parent)]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="project">
  <xsl:param name="head" select="''"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($head, id, '&#10;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', id)">
    <xsl:with-param name="head" select="concat($head, $indent)"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

That way I get the output

```
141
>109
>53
>>24
120
```

It simply processes the elements in document order, I am not sure why your desired output has `120` first unless you want to do some sorting you have not explained. If you want to order by the `id` value as a number use

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="indent" select="'>'"/>

<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:key name="children" match="project[parent]" use="parent/@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="/projects/project[not(parent)]">
    <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(id)"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="project">
  <xsl:param name="head" select="''"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="concat($head, id, '&#10;')"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('children', id)">
    <xsl:sort select="xs:integer(id)"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="head" select="concat($head, $indent)"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

that way you get

```
120
141
>53
>>24
>109
```